# Configure manifest to catch a new location available

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

How can I configure the manifest in order to chatch new location coordinates?
Can I use the BroardcastReceiver to catch new coordinates?

Comment: I'm sorry but how would another application get GPS signal when GPS signal is not available?

Comment: yes you right but I was thinking something like a mock location service. Is there possibile in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this within the application element of your manifest it will call onReceive in your LocationChangedReceiver class whenever a new gps coordinate is obtained:

```
<receiver android:name=".location.LocationChangedReceiver" />
```

LocationChangedReceiver might look like this:

```
public class LocationChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String locationKey = LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED;

        if (intent.hasExtra(locationKey)) {
            Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(locationKey);
            Log.d(TAG, "Got Location! Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Lon:" + location.getLongitude() + ", Alt:" + location.getAltitude() + ", Acc:" + location.getAccuracy());

            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you may find the [passive provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER) helpful.

Helpful

Comment: It seems very helpful. Now I take a look at it to understand if it is exactly what I need.